# Sum of all 3 digit numbers coprime with 12

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

I've managed to find sum of all 3 digit numbers, coprime with $10$ in usual method. In this situation, $12$ has prime factors $2,2$ and $3$, I've failed to model the problem (always missed some cases),so I've tried a different approach.

So there are 4 numbers coprime with $12$ and less than itself: $1,5,7,11$
And I know that $12k+1, 12k+5, 12k+7, 12k+11$ are all those numbers in interval $[100 \dots 999]$. Sum of them gives the solution.
$100 \leq 12k+1 \leq 999$
$9 \leq k \leq 83$
For the first case we have $\sum_{9}^{83}[12k+1]=\sum_{8}^{82}[12k+13]$
2nd: $\sum_{8}^{82}[12k+5]$
3rd: $\sum_{8}^{82}[12k+7]$
4th: $\sum_{8}^{82}[12k+11]$

Sum of them is $12\sum_{8}^{82}[4k+3]$. But I dont know how to compute the sum. I think I should use integral, but my calculus knowledge is not enough to do it myself. I know the answer is 164700 (I made a c++ program). Please, help me to define an integral and compute it, or to find a more simple solution.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the sum of the arithmetic progression $(4k+3)$ from the point you have reached. The first term is $35$,  the last term is $331$ and the number of terms is $82-8+1=75$, so 
$$
12\sum_8^{82}(4k+3)=12\cdot 75\frac{331+35}{2}=900\times 183=164700
$$

Comment: ahh, my problem was about computing that interval difference, I was getting 74 instead of 75.Now I see it, thank you :)